# What is the amplification factor required for android's media recorder to match the output of iOS's AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: android, ios, audio, audio-recording, audio-processing

I have a cross-platform(iOS and Android) app where I will record audio clips then send it to the server to do some machine learning operations. In my iOS app, I use `AVAudioRecorder` for recording the audio. In the Android app, I use MediaRecorder for recording the audio. In the mobile initially, I use m4a format because of size constrictions. After reaching the server I will convert it to `wav` format before using it in the ML operations.

My Problem is, in iOS the AVAudioRecorder by OS default does a factor of Amplification to the raw audio data before we the developer get access to the raw data. But in Android, the MediaRecorder doesn't provide any sort of default Amplification to the raw data. In other words, in iOS I will never get the raw audio stream from the microphone whereas in Android I will always only get the raw audio stream from the microphone. The distinction is clearly visible if you can record the same audio in both iPhone and Android phones side by side with a common audio source, then import the recorded audio in Audacity for visual representation. I have attached a sample representation screenshot below.

[image]

In the image, the first track is the Android recording and the second track is from the iOS recording. When I hear both the audio through headphones I can vaguely distinguish them but when I visualize the data points, you can clearly see the difference in the image. These distinctions are bad for ML operations.

Clearly in the iPhone, there is a certain amplification factor involved which I would like to implement in the Android also.

Is anyone aware of the amplification factor? OR are there any other possible alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the difference is that the effect of Automatic Gain Control.

You can disable this in your app's `AVAudioSession` by setting its mode to `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement` which you do once in your application - usually at startup.  This disables a great deal of input signal processing.

Reading your problem description, you might be better off enabling AGC on Android.

If neither of these yields results, you might want to gain scale both signals so they are just below clipping.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

audio.session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
```